# (Basic) formula construction for a savings goal

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

We have a final figure e.g 1000 dollars and would like to create a formula so that over the course of 52 weeks a descending amount is put towards the savings each week and the final payment in week 52 is 1 dollar.

Ideally the payments would descend by the same amount each fortnight.

We had looked at the (n*(n+1))/2 formula and thought this may be related but couldnt quite see how.

We were hoping to be able to get the final goal to be changed based on an indivudals needs.

eg person 1 may only want 500 dollars at the end of 52 weeks but still only deposits 1 dollar  in week 52.

person 2 may want 10,000 dollars at the end of 52 weeks but still only deposits 1 dollar in week 52.

Any suggestions on where to start with solving this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a sum with finite many terms you can reorder the terms without changing the sum.

Of course
$$
1+2+3+4+5+\cdots + 51 + 52 = 52 + 51 + 50 + \cdots + 3 + 2 + 1 = \frac{52(52+1)}{2} = 1378
$$
Now your total sum $S$is a bit different, so we try
\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{i=1}^{52} 1 + (i-1) d \\
&= 52 + d \sum_{i=1}^{52} i - 52 d \\
&= 52 + 1378 d - 52 d \\
&= 52 + 1326 d \\
d &= \frac{S-52}{1326}
\end{align}
The first payment would be
$$
s_1 = 1 + 51 d
$$

For $S=500$ this gives a difference amount $d=448/1326=224/663=0.33785\ldots$ which will lead to rounding problems if one tries to pay this with real currency units.